# Create a Stacked cloumn chart with HightCharts with percentage on yAxis

Tags: highcharts, percentage, yaxis

I want to use hightCharts to create Stacked column chart ,but what I want is to put percentage on yAxis instead of numbers like the image and in the stacked column the  number of emloyee (3,2,5).. wont change

I know that I should work with stacked percentage column but how can I display the numbers of employee in the stacked column

How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: What you are asking for is the default behavior in Highcharts. Can you explain what problem you're having with it? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/w4keqdfe/ The data labels are the number by default, not the percent.

Comment: thank you I thought that I have only the charts in the hightcharts demo page https://www.highcharts.com/demo

Comment: The demo page is just a set of basic examples. The possibilities are nearly endless. If you start with the percent-stacked chart in the demo, and simply enable the `dataLabels`, this is what you get: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/0xm2u1cq/